# useEffect changing the desired variable but no effect React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, framer-motion

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { colors } from "./components/Animations";

export const tick_cross_animation = {
  hidden: {
    opacity: 0,
    pathLength: 0,
  },
  show: {
    opacity: 1,
    pathLength: 1,
    transition: { duration: 1.25 },
  },
};
const Work = ({ check, setcheck, cross, setcross }) => {
  const [circle_Check, setcircle_Check] = useState(Infinity);
  const circleanimation = {
    hidden: {
      opacity: 0,
      pathLength: 0,
      translateX: 5,
      translateY: 5,
      rotate: -180,
    },
    show: {
      opacity: 1,
      pathLength: 1,

      transition: {
        duration: 1.5,
        yoyo: circle_Check,
      },
    },
  };
  setTimeout(() => {
    setcheck(true);
  }, 1250);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (check || cross === true) {
      setcircle_Check(0);
    } else {
      setcircle_Check(Infinity);
    }
    console.log(
      "Here it is changing but not  " + circle_Check
    );
  }, [check, cross]);

  setTimeout(() => {
    setcross(true);
  }, 3000);
  return (
    <div
      className="wow"
      style={{
        width: "80%",
        margin: "auto",
        height: "20rem",
      }}
    >
      <svg className="progress-icon" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
        <motion.path
          fill="none"
          strokeWidth="2"
          stroke={colors.color_circle}
          d="M 0, 20 a 20, 20 0 1,0 40,0 a 20, 20 0 1,0 -40,0"
          variants={circleanimation}
          initial="hidden"
          animate="show"
        />
        {check && (
          <motion.path
            fill="none"
            strokeWidth="2"
            stroke={colors.color_tick}
            d="M14,26 L 22,33 L 35,16"
            variants={tick_cross_animation}
            initial="hidden"
            animate="show"
          />
        )}
        {cross && (
          <motion.path
            fill="none"
            strokeWidth="2"
            stroke={colors.color_X}
            d="M17,17 L33,33 M33,17 L17,33"
            variants={tick_cross_animation}
            initial="hidden"
            animate="show"
          />
        )}
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Work;
```

This needs to be **synchronized** with the *circleanimation* in show property.
I am working with the 2 useStates just for checking and 1 useEffect. Now when the useEffect runs the code changes the value but the yoyo effect keeps on happening indefinitely. I want it to work with the animation so that it does not last as long as possibel.
[The values do change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWDbw.png)

Answer (score 0):

your `console.log` will always return exact the opposite of the current value as `setState` is asynchronous. Maybe you rely on this and its just that you have the wrong value and you think it should be disabled but you instead just enabled it?

if you want to log the right value use:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setcircle_Check((check || cross === true) ? 0 : Infinity);
}, [check, cross]);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Here it is changing but not  " + circle_Check);
}, [circle_Check]);
```

also your timeouts will be called every rerender. put them inside an effect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    setcheck(true);
  }, 1250);

  setTimeout(() => {
    setcross(true);
  }, 3000);
}, []);
```

Comment: This helped out with the logic but not with the yoyo effect. Everything else changes but not the yoyo effect.

Comment: seams like motion doesn't support changing this dynamically. you can fix it by adding a `key` to the element: `<motion.path key={circle_Check === 0 ? "no-ani" : "ani"} ... />`. this way the element will change and the new animation will apply.